# Unable to resize logical volume

Tags: redhat, lvm, xfs, rhel7

I'm showing a difference in available space in `lvdisplay` vs `df -h`

```
[user@box]~ lvdisplay

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/rhel_data/www
  LV Name                www
  VG Name                rhel_data
  LV UUID                898kpA-ZtbV-RjEB-Qu6V-tM5v-cEvd-KjbtZS
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time box.example.com, 2016-06-14 16:43:11 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                279.38 GiB
  Current LE             71521
  Segments               3
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:6
```

The volume above is mounted at /data/www.

```
[user@box ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-19       47G   47G  3.2M 100% /data/www


[user@box ~]# umount /dev/mapper/rhel_data-www 
umount: /dev/mapper/rhel_data-www: not mounted
[user@box ~]# umount /data/www/

[user@box ~]# resize2fs /dev/mapper/rhel_data-www 
resize2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/mapper/rhel_data-www
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Info about the mount:

```
[user@box]~ mount | grep www
/dev/mapper/luks-e258bd7a-3201-457e-8ade-695c87c53e36 on /data/www type xfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

How do I make use of the additional space that lvdisplay displays?

Comment: What is the filesystem used on that volume?  e.g. `mount | grep www`

Comment: /dev/mapper/luks-e258bd7a-3201-457e-8ade-695c87c53e36 on /data/www **type xfs** (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)

Comment: Use `xfs_growfs /data/www` to use the extra space allocated to that volume.

Comment: Please add that as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***To grow a XFS filesystem to use the space allocated to it after resizing the volume***

```
xfs_growfs /mount/point
```

e.g.

```
xfs_growfs /data/www
```

Comment: Be carefull, xfs can only be grown, not shrinked.